# Representing a positive definite function as the absolute value squared of a fourier series?

Tags: integration, reference-request, fourier-series, orthogonality

For the closed surface of some (pseudo)Riemannian manifold M
 , we're interested in a function $\rho$
  which satisfies:

$$m=\int_{\partial M}\rho(x,y,z) \, d\mathrm{vol}$$

Where $dvol$
  is the volume element on $\partial M$
  and $m$
 (a constant) and $\rho$
  are positive definite quantities ($\rho,m\geq0$
 ). In attempting to represent $\rho$
  by a fourier series of weighted orthogonal basis,

$$\rho(x,y,z)=\Phi(x,y,z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\phi_{n}(x,y,z)$$
  it appears more natural (due to the positive definiteness of $\rho$
 ) to specify instead:

$$\rho(x,y,z)=\Phi^{\star}\Phi$$

Where the star denotes the complex conjugate of the general Fourier series. I get that without a further condition uniqueness of $\Phi$ will be lost. In trying to look up a procedure for this sort of thing, I came across Fredholm theory which seems very relevant. Can anyone point me towards a book on this sort of thing. Thank you!